# How to build component draggable angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm working in an app AngularJS, I need implement a component it can move a element of a list and draggable  to a tree as tree folders. For example in the image, I want move an element or item from one list to one of the nodes or folders tree using "drag and drop" also the list and tree are different divs   but I don't know how to start.

[image: Idea component]

Comment: Have you looked into the html draggable attribute?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable